# Flipping Quicktime preview & capture

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quicktime

I need to horizontally flip some video I'm previewing and capturing. A-la iChat, I have a webcam and want it to appear as though the user is looking in a mirror.

I'm previewing Quicktime video in a `QTCaptureView`. My capturing is done frame-by-frame (for reasons I won't get into) with something like:

```
imageRep = [NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage: [CIImage imageWithCVImageBuffer: frame]];
image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: [imageRep size]];
[image addRepresentation: imageRep];
[movie addImage: image forDuration: someDuration withAttributes: someAttributes];
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by taking the CIImage you're getting from the capture and running it through a Core Image filter to flip the image around.  You would then pass the resulting image into your image rep rather than the original one.  The code would look something like:

```
CIImage* capturedImage = [CIImage imageWithCVImageBuffer:buffer];
NSAffineTransform* flipTransform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
CIFilter* flipFilter;
CIImage* flippedImage;

[flipTransform scaleByX:-1.0 y:1.0]; //horizontal flip
flipFilter = [CIImage filterWithName:@"CIAffineTransform"];
[flipFilter setValue:flipTransform forKey:@"inputTransform"];
[flipFilter setValue:capturedImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
flippedImage = [flipFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
imageRep = [NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage:flippedImage];
...
```

Comment: That looks like it will probably work for recording, but what about in the `QTCaptureView`?

Comment: Something like this might work, using the same setup for the flipFilter variable as above:

[captureView setWantsLayer:YES];
captureView.layer.filters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:flipFilter];

Comment: Awesome - that appears to work great! I had to add a translate transform by the negative of the view's width to move the flipped video back where it should be, but that was easy.

Comment: Just for the record: this seems to really drag the processor. Photobooth and iChat must do it a different way...

Comment: Just noticed QTCaptureView has a delegate method, view:willDisplayImage:, that lets you modify the CIImage it's about to draw. Might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 10):

Nothing like resurrecting an old question. Anyway I came here and almost found what I was looking for thanks to Brian Webster but if anyone is looking for the wholesale solution try this after setting your class as the delegate of the `QTCaptureView` instance:

```
- (CIImage *)view:(QTCaptureView *)view willDisplayImage:(CIImage *)image {
//mirror image across y axis
return [image imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!
it will apply filters to CaptureView, but not to the output video.

```
- (IBAction)Vibrance:(id)sender
{
    CIFilter* CIVibrance = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIVibrance" keysAndValues:
                            @"inputAmount", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:2.0f],
                            nil];
    mCaptureView.contentFilters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:CIVibrance];
}
```

btw, you can apply any filters from this ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html