# How I can mirror an image after selecting through image picker using swift?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

```
@IBAction func mirrorBtn(sender: AnyObject){
    self.makeMirroredImage(imageView)
    pickImage.image = imageView

}

func makeMirroredImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    var flippedOrientation: UIImageOrientation = .UpMirrored
    switch image.imageOrientation {
    case .Down:
        flippedOrientation = .DownMirrored
    case .Left:
        flippedOrientation = .LeftMirrored
    default :
        flippedOrientation = .LeftMirrored
    }

    let flippedImage: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: image.CGImage!, scale: image.scale, orientation: flippedOrientation)
    return flippedImage
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code that you have tried?

Comment: @Asdrubal i have my function for mirroring.It is not working

Comment: You mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936590/flip-nsimage-on-both-axes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the image is selected you should be able to invert it using a translation. I'm not a professional with iOS/swift, but in Android I accomplished this by setting the `X` and `Y` translation to `-1`. Hope this puts you on the right track